# Why can't my Perl script in ~/bin find relative file paths?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; 
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $file = './example.xml';
my $doc = $parser->parse_file( $file );
print ref( $doc ), "\n";
```

When I move this script and the example.xml-file to /home/me/ then the script works.
When I move the script and the example.xml-file to /home/me/bin/ then the script doesn't find the example.xml-file.
Is this some special-feature of the bin-directory?

Comment: This is not a programming question but a general computer user question about how executables are located by the shell. Voting to move to SU.

Comment: Seconded... ...

Comment: It's a pretty clear question. I understand it just fine, and Nate gives the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.  But, it'll be opening the file from "`./example.xml`", which should be your current working directory (`cwd`, in Unix parlance).  It's probably getting your script from the command search path (`$PATH` environment variable).

Refer to it by absolute pathname, and it'll work fine.  I'd also recommend reading up on `cwd`, `pwd` and "`man pwd`".

Comment: Or, best of all, use FindBin to locate the script path ...

Comment: willert: No, don't use FindBin: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=41213